# Convert mm into pixel in cn1

Tags: codenameone

I've set margin in mm in theme. Most of the time, I need margin value in mm but I need it in the pixel in some cases as well but other than margin, every style of that UIID in the theme are applicable to all the component. So how can I convert mm into pixel programmatically

Update:

[image]

I have a "Container" uiid in the theme which I've set in mm. So everything that have "Container" uiid will take the margin unit in mm. However in some components, I need marginTop in pixel ie. 1px but all the features of "Container" uiid should be there too. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING:** Don't ever change the padding/styling of the `Container` UIID unless you want to break everything within your app!

Notice that setting the `Style` object of an individual object should be fine though.

```
style.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS);
```

or:

```
style.setPaddingUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_PIXELS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS, Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS);
```

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. I've updated the question, have a look.

Comment: Updated my answer